# Images that load as they appear in the page via jQuery slide / scrollable?

Tags: jquery, image

I noticed that the images in [this site](http://walkyrie.org/) load in an interesting way.

The site consist in 3 pictures (left. right and middle). After clicking the right picture it moves to the center via jQuery slide / scrollable (i guess) and the new picture on the right loads (it wasn't previously loaded).

How is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually looking at the code, I'm guessing there's something like this happening:

- on click of the right image, slide two images left. this will be a live event listener, probably
- ajax call for the next image
- on return, load that image into some sort of div, like

I'll dive into the code now and see if that's what's happening. It's pretty slick though.

---

Edit

It looks like all the images have a div loaded from the start. Then there's a jquery function that puts the image in the div when it's visible.

Comment: Did you spot the jQuery function that does that? So, is not a plugin?

Comment: It's all in http://walkyrie.org/js/common.js. It looks like if the image is in view, it gets $.scrollable, and if it has that, init() throws the image in. I'm not exactly clear on how it works though.

Comment: @janoChen look at the `gogo` part. I think that's where the script checks to see if things are in the right place, and then the show starts.